# JavaScript syntax to find dates within last three years

Tags: javascript, date

What is the proper syntax to see if a given date falls within 3 years
from todays date? I need it to actually do three years not just take
the year of todays date and subtract 3 which may not actually be three
full years ago. In other words if we are mid way through this year. I
need to go back mid way through the year three years ago.

Basically I have some records that have dates attached to them and I
only want to display them if they are between today and exactly three
years ago.

THANKS

Comment: What format is the date you're trying to compare/assess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Date` objects can be subtracted to give a difference in milliseconds:

```
var now = new Date;
var then = new Date(2008, 10, 7);

if ((now - then) < 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 3)
```

`1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 3` is three years in milliseconds, discounting leap years and leap seconds.

Comment: yup, that's what I was going to write - leap years are the only significant source of error.